# Rails Show data in another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, controller, relationship, custom-routes

I need to show data of other controller in my central controller
Central = patients_controller.rb
Other = weights_controller.rb
Controllers have relationship like this
MODELS:
patient.rb =   has_many :weight
weight.rb = belongs_to :patient

I need to show only weights of one patient in view
I try this:
Create route = get 'peso/:id/', to: 'patients#weight'
create a def in controller patients =

```
def weights  
end
```

Before this i try to call in view this:

```
<%= @patient.weight %>
```

But i cant show any result  anyone can help me.

Comment: Are you able to perform other crud operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to show data
in patient controller i make this

in controller patients

```
  def weight  
  end
```

And created view weight.html.slim

```
 p#notice = notice
    .row
      p
      table
thead
tr
    th Nome:
    th Sexo:
    th Data de nascimento:
    th Idade:


       tbody
  tr
    td = @patient.name
    td = @patient.sex.name
    td = @patient.born
    td = ((Date.today - @patient.born) / 365).to_i
      p

      table
thead
  tr
    th Plano:
    th Senha de internação:
    th Admimissão:
    th Altura:
tbody
  tr
    td = @patient.plan.name
    td = @patient.pass
    td = @patient.admission
    - if @patient.weight.first.inch != nil
        td = @patient.weight.first.inch
    - else
        td = 'Paciente sem altura registrada'
      p
      table
        thead
          tr
            th Data
            th Peso
            th IMC:

        strong pesos:
tbody
  - @patient.weight.each do |m|
    tr
      - if m.date != nil
          td = m.date
      - else
          td = 'Sem pesos registrados'

      - if m.weight != nil
          td  = m.weight
      - else
          td  = 'sem peso registrado'

      - if @patient.weight.first.inch != nil
          td  = (m.weight / (@patient.weight.first.inch**2).to_f).round(2)
      - else
          td  = 'sem dados para este calculo'

      br´
```

and in index.html.erb

```
<td><a href="/peso/<%= patient.id %>" target="_blank">Relatorio</a></td>
```

In routes.rb

```
get 'peso/:id/', to: 'patients#weight'
```

And solved my problem